# Why does space appear at the right of the three main buttons?

Tags: space, css

See the following link: http://www.howru.nl/preken/new/test3.html

For some reason I keep getting space at the right of the three main buttons.
To better identity this on this forum, I've enabled the border of the relevant table temporary.

The issue is inside the following class I reckon:

```
.button
{
    display: block;
    width: 350px;
    height: 135px;

    margin-left: 7px;
    margin-right: 7px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;

    text-decoration: none;

    background-position: top;

    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

The specified width is the actual width of the background image.
The full CSS sheet can be found at http://www.howru.nl/preken/new/styles.css

Right column (text) should float at the right, as is the case currently. Left column (buttons) should float at the left (as is currently the case), and the center picture should float in the center. Strange thing is the left column takes more space in the table, while none have a fixed width.

Ideally I don't want to specify a width of a column twice (for the TD and for the content, in case of a BG image on the display-block'd content); in the proposed solutions below the display-block'd  has a width specified (width of the background image) and the parent TD element as well... That is what I don't like and for which I started this post. Because I still don't understand why the TD's aren't equally sharing the available table space:

Now column 1 (left) seems to take the most, while it doesn't need so much, the second takes a little less, and the right column takes only what was specified for the inner width, whilst the left (1st) column has the same (width specified for the content instead of the TD) and does not stick to that width apparantly, while the right TD does...)

Both in IE as Opera I get this; any idea what I am missing??!

Goal is to understand what is happening, and why. So I'm not looking for a cheap fix - as one can thing of 100 'ugly' ways to do this.

Comment: what space are you talking about?

Comment: do you want the right column to be full size?

Answer (score 1):

here are the changes i have made. Try this. Btw you should use % instead of px

```
.top {
vertical-align: top;
width: 350px;
}
```

removed float from .blkright

```
.blkright {
}

.title {
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: bold;
letter-spacing: -1px;
padding-bottom: 5px;
text-align: center;
}

.column {
   margin-left: 12px;
   overflow: hidden;
   width: 325px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change right table .top .column width in the  to change this space to right of buttons

```
.column {
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 5px 5px 25px;
    width: 290px;
```

(originally width was 250px) because it is trying to fit the width: 100% you have set
you can also remove the 250px , since the right column is the only column you've set a width on

Comment: indeed that is the only column I specified a width for, but this is actually the width of the DIV inside the TD. If this would be the reason (equal width distribution) than I'd still expect the center en left column to equally share the remaining width (but now, the left column is taking a lot more - for no apparant reason?)

Comment: you could also set a width for each column if you want to keep the right text div at 250px (right now the 3 columns are are coming up as 400,350,300) , so for example set the left TD to 350, center TD with image to 400, right td to 350, or something similar and you can keep your right div/ text floating right

Comment: Indeed that's more what I like. One way to do it would be to set fixed widths for the left and right column I guess.. In CSS, as TD's can't have attribute 'width' in XHTML1.1. The rest of the space is then 'dynamically' taken by the centre column. It still doesn't make all three columns share the space equally, but that may not be necessary. Specifing three widths would mean I'd have to respecify everytime I'd change the width of the body; with the center column dynamic it just fills the remaining space and center equally.

Answer (score 0):

I am not ultimately sure how you want the rest (e.g. the text paragraph) aligned then, but here is my approach.

First, give each body-column a class or an id. You assign these classes to the three `<td>`s respectively.

```
.content-left {
   float: left;
}


.content-mid {
   float: left;
}

.content-right {
   display: table-row;
}
```

Although this solution takes a bit more effort than `IanO.S.`'s, this solution is also more dynamic. If your button or image sizes change someday you don't have to hack into your code, find and edit your pixel-widths.

Comment: right column (all text) should float at the right, as it does now. Buttons should float left, and the picture in the center column should be centered in the remaining width. See also my note on IanOS's reply.

Answer (score 0):

Add declaration of width on the first table cell

```
.top:first{
width: 364px;
}
```

and you wont see any spaces anymore

Comment: true, but the width isn't 20% of the full width, so don't like this solution :)

Comment: OK, so try 364px :) or is this going to be fluid layout?

Comment: Also see my comment on IanOS; the combination of your's and his comment is the final answer I guess; having the width's of the actual TD's unspecified whilst the content is specified width (at least in the left and right case) simply doesn't make the table equally distribute the available width apparantly.